# Time difference

Tags: mysql, datetime

I was working with SQL and I found something unusual. I was calculating the time difference between two datetimes in `h:m:s` format using SQL

```
select time_format(timediff(
    '2015-09-12 18:47:15',
    '2015-09-12 18:38:33'),'%h:%i:%s') as time_down
```

This returns 12:08:39 which is incorrect and it should be 00:08:39

```
select time_format(timediff(
    '2015-09-12 18:10:04',
    '2015-09-12 16:34:05'),'%h:%i:%s') as time_down
```

This returns 1:35:59 which is correct

But when I changed %h to %H the result of the first query was correct.

What is the explanation?

Comment: What are you trying to get to with time_down? Is it possible that it would be more than 12 hours? What happens if it spans "midnight" of a particular day, as timediff() won't take the date (only the time) into account.....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your situation is simple. You're trying to format a time result that is `00:08:42` and according with the [MySQL date and time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), `%h` for `Hour (01..12)`, you're converting `00`(hour) to `12`. If you change it for `%H` you will get the desired result `%H` for `Hour (00..23)`.

### Try this test:

```
mysql> select
    -> timediff('2015-09-12 18:47:15','2015-09-12 18:38:33') as timediffA,
    -> timediff('2015-09-12 18:10:04','2015-09-12 16:34:05') as timediffB,
    -> time_format(timediff('2015-09-12 18:47:15','2015-09-12 18:38:33'),'%h:%i:%s') as time_A_wtimeformath,
    -> DATE_FORMAT(timediff('2015-09-12 18:47:15','2015-09-12 18:38:33'),'%h:%i:%s') as time_A_wdateformath, 
    -> DATE_FORMAT(timediff('2015-09-12 18:47:15','2015-09-12 18:38:33'),'%H:%i:%s') as time_A_wdateformatH, 
    -> time_format(timediff('2015-09-12 18:10:04','2015-09-12 16:34:05'),'%h:%i:%s') as time_B_wtimeformath,
    -> DATE_FORMAT(timediff('2015-09-12 18:10:04','2015-09-12 16:34:05'),'%h:%i:%s') as time_B_wdateformath,
    -> DATE_FORMAT(timediff('2015-09-12 18:10:04','2015-09-12 16:34:05'),'%H:%i:%s') as time_B_wdateformatH;
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| timediffA | timediffB | time_A_wtimeformath | time_A_wdateformath | time_A_wdateformatH | time_B_wtimeformath | time_B_wdateformath | time_B_wdateformatH |
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 00:08:42  | 01:35:59  | 12:08:42            | 12:08:42            | 00:08:42            | 01:35:59            | 01:35:59            | 01:35:59            |
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0,01 sec)

mysql>
```

Try it in [**SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/20140).